# What does it mean by a library of code? And how do I access one?

Tags: c++, build

http://troy.spunak.com/TAPsDoc/html/index.html

Here is an example of .cpp and .h files that someone has written and made as a library.

How do I gain access to his functions and classes (Which directory do I place them in after downloading, and if I have to compile them? 
How do I compile them?)?

Do I have to create a main function and run my code or does the library come with a 
main  function and I use the one provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A library is a reusable module that is used precompiled in particular system configurations.

How you use a library depends on your particular development environment, but with some versions of C++ you tell the linker where the library is (*.dll or *.lib, say) and tell it to incorporate the library in your executable (static linking) or use it as it needs (dynamic linking).

To use a particular library, the library designer may have included an IDE project file or a makefile so that you can build the library from source.  Or, they might just provide the library as a binary.  In either case, they might provide instructions on using the library, or show some examples.  Actually, this one does:

[http://troy.spunak.com/TAPsDoc/html/*ex*_c_d_r__fns_8cpp-example.html](http://troy.spunak.com/TAPsDoc/html/_ex__c_d_r__fns_8cpp-example.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: So do I have to download all the .cpp and .h to use this library, I don't see a link to download all the .cpp and .h. Also can I just use individual .cpp files or do I have to compile all the .cpp and .h files that the author has given? This is his main website [link](http://troy.spunak.com/)

Comment: No idea. I couldn't see any links from that page. Maybe contact him?